# 1860. Incremental Memory Leak

Tags: python, performance, memory

I might be asking an unimportant question but I have noticed that very similar codes have 2 different run times!

The below 2 codes are both valid solutions to the problem in Python. However, when running both codes 1 million times each on multiple different inputs (Random values between 1 and 1000), I got the following results:

1st Code    : 2.53 seconds

2nd Code    : 28.8 seconds

Any ideas why is that the reason? Because in my eyes they both look very similar and gave the exact same output every time.

PS. the following is the code blocks for each

## **1st Code**

```py
def memLeak1(self, memory1: int, memory2: int):
        i = 1;
        while memory2 >= 0 and memory1 >= 0:
            if memory1 >= memory2:
                if memory1 >= i:
                    memory1 -= i;
                else:
                    break;
            else:
                if memory2 >= i:
                    memory2 -= i;
                else:
                    break;
            i += 1;

        return [i,memory1,memory2];
```

## **2nd Code**

```py
def memLeak2(self, memory1: int, memory2: int):
        i = 1
        while memory1 >= i or memory2 >= i:
            if memory1 >= memory2:
                memory1 -= i
            else:
                memory2 -= i
        i += 1

        return [i, memory1, memory2]
```

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that in the **2nd Code** "i" is being incremented outside of the loop which did cause the program to loop though the program extra amount of times.